# E: Package 'monodevelop' has no installation candidate

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am very new to linux as well as Raspberry Pi. Recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4. Trying to install Monodevelop as I would like to make apps. Following the directions from [Monodevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin-debian) I am getting the following error.

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package monodevelop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'monodevelop' has no installation candidate
```

Thinking that maybe there is something wrong with my installation I have formatted and reinstalled Raspberry Pi OS [Within Raspberry Pi Imager I have chosen Raspberry Pi OS (Other) -> Raspberry Pi OS Full (32-bit)]

Despite reinstalling the OS I am getting the exact same error.

Doing research about this error still leaves question marks as I am still not understanding 1, what the issue is 2, what are next steps to address this.

Can't remember where I came across this bit of info, but someone has mentioned trying to do a cache search as shown below you will see that Monodevelop does come pre-installed on the Raspberry Pi OS

```
sudo apt-cache search monodevelop
libgtk2-sourceview2-perl - enhanced source code editor widget
libicsharpcode-nrefactory-cecil5.0-cil - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - Cecil back-end
libicsharpcode-nrefactory-cil-dev - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - Development files
libicsharpcode-nrefactory-csharp5.0-cil - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - C# Component
libicsharpcode-nrefactory-ikvm5.0-cil - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - IKVM back-end
libicsharpcode-nrefactory-xml5.0-cil - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - XML
libicsharpcode-nrefactory5.0-cil - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - Core
nrefactory-samples - C# Parsing and Refactoring Library - Sample programs
xamarin-gtk-theme - Xamarin gtk+-2.0 theme engine and themes
monodevelop-nunit - NUnit plugin for MonoDevelop
```

I don't know what I need to do with that bit of info. Do I uninstall those packages that it came pre-loaded with it? Really don't know what to do at this point.

Within this stackexchange a possible solution was to install gdeb to properly install the software: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50511/127602

Don't know if this is a valid path to go down.

Can someone make some recommendations for me try? Would really like to get Monodevelop installed. That is my hope.

**Update 1**:

Ran the following commmand

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list    
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster main
```

Would like to mention that I have tried modifying the sourc list "mono-official-vs.list" file. Currently, that's what the file says.

Have in the past updated the file to include the following...

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster main
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian buster main
```

Or...

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster main
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster/snapshots/6.10.0 main
```

The last one generated the following error message

```
W: Conflicting distribution: https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster/snapshots/6.10.0 InRelease (expected stable-buster/snapshots/6.10.0 but got buster)
```

Both of which have failed to install monodevelop. Any other suggestions that you think might help, I am all willing to try.

**Update 2**:

Started from scratch again. Here are the steps that I have taken.

- Raspberry Pi Imager [Formatted SD card, just in case left over data?]
- Once format was complete chosen to install "Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) [Recommended choice]
- After installation and boot up. Ran the update recommended update when it was offered
- Once updated was completed went to Monodevelop website and followed their step-by-step guide to install their software on Debian 10 see output below...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dirmngr is already the newest version (2.2.12-1+rpi1+deb10u1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 149 kB of archives.
After this operation, 156 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirror.pit.teraswitch.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf apt-transport-https all 1.8.2.2 [149 kB]
Fetched 149 kB in 1s (177 kB/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 98394 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.8.2.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.8.2.2) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.8.2.2) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.BvYJQx2owl/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
gpg: key A6A19B38D3D831EF: public key "Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster main
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get:1 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster InRelease [5,875 B]
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease            
Hit:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:4 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian vs-buster/main armhf Packages [47.8 kB]
Fetched 53.7 kB in 1s (43.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package monodevelop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'monodevelop' has no installation candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please execute this command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list`, [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/119093/edit) your question and add the output of the command to it.

Comment: @Ingo, Post has been updated. Please check. If there are any other suggestions feel free to mention.